# Loop through multiple forms and tha loop through each form elements and gather their attributes

Tags: javascript, forms

I can have one or multiple forms in a HTML. I want to get all the forms that have an attribute `[data-form]`.

I need to cycle through the elements of each form and get the elements, and add in an Array the 'name' and 'value' for each element;

I need to identify separately the submit button.

In the code below, I get the forms, how can I access the attributes of inputs(without querying the specific element) and know which is submit?

```
formAttr = data-form

    document.querySelectorAll(formAttr).forEach(function (form, index) {
            // create a new object for the form
            arr[index] = {};
            arr[index]['Ref'] = form
            for (var element in form.elements){
                // code to add
            }
        });

 <form action="#" method="get" data-form>
            <select>
                <option value="0">1</option>
                <option value="1">2</option>
                <option value="2">3</option>
            </select>
            <div class="arucio">  
             <input type="text" name="firstname">
             <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Paul">
            </div>
             <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with next code snippet:

Html:

```
<form id='f1'>
    <input type='text' value="input_value" />
    <input type='number' value="100" />
</form>

<form id='f2' data-form=true>
    <textarea>Some text</textarea>
</form>

<form id='f3' data-form=true>
    <select>
        <option>One</option>
        <option>Two</option>
        <option>Three</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

JS:

```
let arr = [];
document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach(function (form, index) {
    arr[index] = {
                'ref': form,
    };
    let values = [];
    for (i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
            switch (form.elements[i].nodeName) {
                case 'INPUT':
                    values.push({
                        'type': 'INPUT',
                    'value': form.elements[i].value
                });
                    break;
                case 'TEXTAREA':
                    values.push({
                        'type': 'TEXTAREA',
                    'value': form.elements[i].value
                });
                    break;
                case 'SELECT':
                    values.push({
                        'type': 'SELECT',
                    'value': form.elements[i].value
                });
                    break;

        }
    }    
    arr[index]['values'] = values;
});
```

Now you get all you need in arr variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is **for-in** loop. **For-in** loop iterates only through object keys and not from actual array. For more details please see link of MDN documentation of for-in loop [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). You can use for loop or to lessen the code you can use map as shown in following code snippet.

```
           formAttr = "[data-form]"
           var arr =[];

            document.querySelectorAll(formAttr).forEach(function (form, index){
                    let values =[];
                    arr[index] = {'ref':form};
                    var elements = [].slice.call(form.elements);
                    elements.map((element)=>{
                       values.push({'type':element.type,'value':element.value})
                   });
                   arr[index]['values']=values;
                });
                }
```